# How to extract JSON value from SQL where where column values sometimes empty

Tags: sql, mariadb, mariasql

I have a table with column 'sometimesjson' that somtimes contains a value like this:

```
[{"id":111,"nam":"PROVIDER_this_one","qty":null}]
```

and sometimes the field completely is empty, not just "[]" but completely empty/null field.

So I try to return "PROVIDER_this_one" with this, but errors...

```
CASE WHEN JSON_VALID(sometimesjson) 
            THEN 
            JSON_EXTRACT(sometimesjson, '$.nam') 
            AS 'FROMJSON' 
             ELSE null
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: _Error, errors, I see no errors_ Maybe you could share yours with us

Comment: I figured it out.  I guess because the json actually is array, the correct way for me to call "nam" for every value in the array within that table field was this... '$[*].nam'  instead of '$.nam'     it's working now.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. I guess because the json value actually is an array, the correct way for me to call "nam" for every value in that table field value array was this... **'$[*].nam'** instead of '$.nam' it's working now with...

```
    CASE WHEN JSON_VALID(sometimesjson) 
            THEN 
            JSON_EXTRACT(sometimesjson, '$[*].nam') 
            AS 'FROMJSON' 
             ELSE null
```